How to implement an eSim on iPhone?
I need to install the eSim from the app automatically.
I added this code:
let ctpr = CTCellularPlanProvisioningRequest()
let ctcp =  CTCellularPlanProvisioning()

But when I call this next code:
ctcp.addPlan(with: ctpr)

I get this case. unknown
the result is: .unknown case
It's always returns 'unknown'.
I also sent a request on Apple eSim entitlements a long time ago.
But they didn't respond.

Do you have the required entitlement for your provisioning profile from Apple?  Without the entitlement you can't provision an eSim.

@Paulw11 I sent a request but they didn't respond.
How can I check? or contact them?
